# R- probability density from a discrete named vector

Tags: r, probability

I have a named vector, modVect, which contains the probability value for each one of the names (-.01, -.02.... which are discrete error values).

```
head(modVect)
-.01         -.02         -.03         -.04         -.05         -.06 
0.0006927649 0.0033267561 0.0080302663 0.0065196742 0.0018305703 0.0003929703
```

I want to simulate error values based on these probabilities. How can I do this using either a probability  density function or a kernel density estimation? So far I have done this

```
xseq<-as.numeric(names(modVect))
plot(xseq, modVect)
y<-kde(modVect)
```

but this is incorrect because it doesn't interpret the modVect values as probabilities. I hope there is a function that can create a pdf from probabilities.

Thanks

Comment: You need to clarify what you want. Densities are NOT probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

To sample with probs, use `sample` with `probs`.

```
N <- 1000
sample(xseq, N, replace=TRUE, probs=modVect)
```

Comment: That is the sort of function I was looking for, but my modVect vector contains probability densities, not probabilities. Will it still function correctly?

Comment: Let me guess: you got `modVect` out of a call to `kde` or `density`. If so, it'll be a grid of equally-spaced points and everything's fine; `sample` will normalise the probabilities to sum to 1.

Comment: Also, do you know of a way to bias this sample? I want to include weights from an autocorrelation that would change the probabilities in this modVect vector. I tried using ecdf but it does not take in probabilities. For example, if the last sample was "-.07", I want to bias the sampling, or just change the next updated modVect negatively to reflect the influence from the lag correlation from the last sample.